# javascript remove blank object

Tags: javascript

i have an array of objects that looks like: (obfuscated values)

```
[
  {
    "title": "l",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "x",
        "bodyPart": "x",
        "equipment": "x",
        "gifUrl": "h",
        "name": "x",
        "target": "x",
        "broad_target": "x",
        "ppl": "p",
        "thumbnail": "h",
        "heatmap_target": "u"
      }
    ]
  },
  {}
]
```

if you notice, there is a blank `{}`.

my attempt to remove these is:

```
const cleanEmpty = obj => Object.entries(output)
                    .map(([k,v])=>[k,v && typeof v === "object" ? cleanEmpty(v) : v])
                    .reduce((a,[k,v]) => (v == null ? a : (a[k]=v, a)), {});
```

this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Array.filter to filter the blank objects like this :

```js
const arr = [
  {
    foo: "bar"
  },
  {}
]

const newArr = arr.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).length >= 1)

console.log(newArr) //[{foo: "bar"}]
```